# Why is $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ uniformly convergent in $|y| \geq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In the Complex Analysis text by Ahlfors', he says that it's easy to see that the series
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-k)^2}$$ converges uniformly in the set $\{x+iy:|y| \geq 1\}.$

I can't see why is it the case. I tried using the Weierstrass M-test, but the bounds I got were $\left|\frac{1}{(z-n)^2} \right| \leq 1$ and the series $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty 1$ diverges.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't converge uniformly in $\{z : \lvert\Im z\rvert \geqslant 1\}$, only locally uniformly.

Comment: @DanielFischer In that case, how can he justify taking the limit of the series as $|y| \to \infty$ term-by-term (at page 189)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the series converges only locally uniformly in $\{z : \lvert \Im z\rvert \geqslant 1\}$.

On p. 188, he writes:

> It is uniformly convergent on any compact set after omission of the terms which become infinite on the set.

But, in the part in question, Ahlfors doesn't speak about the convergence of the sequence on that set, rather

> For $z = x + iy$ we have (Chap. 2, Sec. 3.2, Ex. 4)
>   $$\lvert \sin \pi z\rvert^2 = \cosh^2 \pi y - \cos^2 \pi x$$
>   and hence $\pi^2/\sin^2\pi z$ tends uniformly to $0$ as $\lvert y\rvert \to \infty$. But it is easy to see that the function $(7)$ has the same property. indeed, the convergence is uniform for $\lvert y\rvert \geqslant 1$, say, and the limit for $\lvert y\rvert \to \infty$ can thus be obtained by taking the limit in each term.

refers to the uniformity - in $y$ - of the convergence *for any fixed* $x$, or, stronger, for $x$ in any bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The exposition is indeed not immaculately clear.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I've started reading the book a few months ago, and I try to solve all exercises. Whenever I'm having difficulty I post it here, and it seems like you answered most of questions. I was wondering if you already read the whole thing? and if you recommend it for self study?

Comment: It's been a while since I read it, but yes, I've read it completely (but I have forgotten a lot). It's one of the great classics, a good choice for self study. But one should also look at other expositions with sometimes other angles of view. I can also recommend Rudin (Real and Complex Analysis), and Fischer/Lieb (A Course in Complex Analysis).

Comment: I still don't think I get it. *What* exactly converges uniformly as  $|y| \geq 1$? Is is the series as $|y| \to \infty$, or the convergence of the series itself?

Comment: The series (let's denote its sum by $s(z)$) converges uniformly on $\{z:\lvert x\rvert\leqslant K,\lvert y\rvert\geqslant1\}$ for any fixed $K$. Hence, you can take the limit $\lvert y\rvert\to\infty$ termwise and conclude $\lim\limits_{\lvert y\rvert\to\infty}s(z)=0$ - uniformly for $\lvert x\rvert\leqslant K$. Now, $s$ has period $1$, so if you chose $K\geqslant\frac12$, that proves $\lim\limits_{\lvert y\rvert\to\infty}s(z)=0$ uniformly for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $Y>0$ so that $\lvert y\rvert\geqslant Y\Rightarrow\lvert s(z)\rvert<\varepsilon$.

Comment: How can you show that the convergence is uniform? I couldn't do it with the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Which convergence?

Comment: Of the series $s(z)$

Comment: @user1337 When $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant K$, then for all $\lvert n\rvert > K$, you have $\left\lvert \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{(\lvert n\rvert - K)^2}$. When $\lvert n\rvert \geqslant 2K$, you have $\lvert z-n\rvert \geqslant \lvert n\rvert/2$, so each term is bounded by $\frac{4}{n^2}$. Now choose $N \geqslant 2K$ so large that $\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{8}$. Then $\left\lvert s(z) - \sum\limits_{\lvert n\rvert \leqslant N}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}\right\rvert < \varepsilon$ for $z$ with $\lvert x\rvert\leqslant K$ and $z \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note that the convergence is _not_ uniform on all of $\mathbb{C}$, nor on all of $\{z : \lvert y\rvert \geqslant 1\}$. We must restrict the real part to get uniform convergence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9952/discussion-between-user1337-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 0):

Lars Ahlfors is right. Let us consider (as usually, $[x]$ denotes the integer part of a real number $x$)$$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {|z-k|^2 }=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {(x-k)^2+y^2} \le  \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {(x-k)^2+1}=$$ $$\sum_{k-[x]=-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {(x-[x]-k+[x])^2+1}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {(x-[x]-n)^2+1} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {(n-1)^2+1}+ 1+$$  $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac 1 {(n+1)^2+1} .$$

Comment: The convergence is not uniform in the sense that the partial sums $\sum_{k = -m}^n \frac{1}{(z-k)^2}$ converge uniformly. For every cutoff $(m,n)$, the term $\frac{1}{(z-(n+1))^2}$ has absolute value $1$ at $(n+1) + i$.

Comment: I don't understand your arguments. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: To say that the partial fraction series converges uniformly on $M = \{z : \lvert y\rvert \geqslant 1\}$ means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, you can choose an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left\lvert \sum_{\lvert n\rvert > N} \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}\right\rvert < \varepsilon$ _for all_ $z \in M$. But given any $N$, you have $(N+1) + i \in M$, and that gives you a term in the remainder of the series with value $-1$. The next few terms also have relatively large absolute value, but the real parts aren't large enough to cancel the $-1$, you are always left with a remainder of absolute value $> c$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You are right. I derived the upper bound for the modulus of the series under consideration.