# Show that $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-z)^2}$ converges uniformly on compact sets in $\Bbb C - \Bbb Z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-z)^2}$$

converges uniformly on compact sets in $\Bbb C - \Bbb Z$, and is a continuous function there.

Here is the original dutch version:

[image]

My first idea is to write this like:

$$1/z^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(n-z)^2+1/(n+z)^2$$

And then use the Weisterstraas M test. But this didn't work.
Any other ideas ?

Comment: this might help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458933/why-is-sum-k-infty-infty-frac1z-n2-uniformly-convergent-in-y?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Any compact set $K$ in $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb Z$ is contained in some disk $B(0,N)$, $N\in\mathbb N$. At the same time $K$ has a positive minimal distance from $\mathbb Z$, $0<\delta=d(K, \mathbb Z)$, since $d(x,\mathbb Z)=\min_{n\in\mathbb Z}|x-n|$ is a continuous function.

Then for any $z\in K$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}\right|&<\frac{1}{δ^2}&&\text{ for }|n|\le N\\
\left|\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}\right|&<\frac{1}{(|n|-|N|)^2}&&\text{ for }|n|\ge N+1
\end{align}
so that
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}\left|\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}\right|\le \frac{2N+1}{δ^2}+2\cdot\frac{\pi^2}6
$$
By the Weierstraß M test convergence is uniform on $K$.

---

Which means that the idea in the question was right, one just needs to take out a larger middle part.

Comment: The only thing I doubt about is that I know the weiserstrass test for $n ∈ℕ$. You are using $n∈ℤ$.

Comment: That's why there is a factor $2$ in the second term. You apply the convergence test once for $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \tfrac1{(z-n)^2}$ and once for $\sum_{n=-N-1}^{-\infty} \tfrac1{(z-n)^2}=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \tfrac1{(z+n)^2}$, both under the assumption that $|z|\le N$, so that $|z-n|\ge |n|-|z|\ge|n|-|N|$.

Comment: Okay. That I understand. So you split the series up in three parts. Two parts are uniform convergent, and one part is finite (constant). But I don't see how I can now justify that that the whole series is uniform convergent.

Comment: Im thinking, that I don't really know how uniform convergence on a series on $\Bbb Z$ is even defined. But I guess it means that:
$$∀ϵ>0,∃N,∀n>N,∀z∈A:|\sum_{|k|<n}f_n(z)-\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(z)|<ϵ$$

And that is:
$$∀ϵ>0,∃N,∀n>N,∀z∈A:|\sum_{|k|≥n}f_n(z)|<ϵ$$

So, in that sense. It seems like I don't have to worry about the middle part anyway.

Comment: Yes and no. The middle part should not have any singularities. The convergence definition is correct this way.

Comment: What do you mean with singularity ? And could you explain me in detail how you go from unifrom convergence from those two outer parts to uniform convergence of the whole series on $ℤ$? :-)

Comment: All functions in the series should be continuous on the considered domain. This is here not a problem under the assumptions, but "don't have to worry about the middle part" goes a little too far to the other side. As for the convergence, in the end you have the sum over three continuous functions.

Answer (score -2):

i think (by taking euler product) that the function is about

$$ \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}log(sin(z)/z) $$

THE infinite Euler product is equal to $ sin(z) $ up to some constant